# Can't get UIBezierPath onto of MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've got a MKMap, on top of this I have a little legend. The labels & images inside the legend successfully show on top of the map, but the rectangle/bezier itself doesn't show.
I've tried adding it as a subview and that fails. Is there a way around this?

I need touch to still be enabled for the map.

Thanks.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //TODO
        //Hover view for touching icons
        //Get rect on top of map as well
        //Border on frame
        //IsIpad slight larger frame/text/image
    int conX = [GeneralHelper GetCenteredXPosForObj:220 :self];
    int conY = 60;

    //Create box
    CGRect container = CGRectMake(conX, conY, 220, 50);
    UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:container cornerRadius:5.0];
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
    [path fillWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.7];
    //How to add to subview..?

    //NZPost image 38x37
    UIImageView *nzPostImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(conX + 20, conY+15, 25, 24)];
    [nzPostImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-map-post.png"]];
    [self addSubview:nzPostImageView];

    //NZPost label
    LegendLabel *postLabel = [[LegendLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(conX + 50, 78, conY, 15) ];
    postLabel.text = @"NZ post";
    [self addSubview: postLabel];

    //Incharge image 38x38
    UIImageView *inChargeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(conX + 120, conY+15, 25, 24)];
    [inChargeImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-map-incharge.png"]];
    [self addSubview:inChargeImageView];

    //Incharge label
    LegendLabel *inChargeLabel = [[LegendLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(conX + 150, conY+18, 60, 15) ];
    inChargeLabel.text = @"In charge";
    [self addSubview: inChargeLabel];


}
```

Comment: What class it that drawRect: in? Have you tried using MKOverlays?

Comment: Doing that in the subclass of the "View" object create in storyboard